# How do I change the axis numbers in a matplotlib colormap image?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have some python code that applies a 2-D function over a range of x and y values, and uses matplotlib to plot the results as a colormap. However, the axes on this plot show the integer indexes of the output array. I would instead like these axes to show the range of the x and y values, from `-1.0` to `1.0`, like a typical graphing application would look.

How do I set the range of the axes?

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# let x, y values be in range of (-1, 1)
x, y = np.mgrid[-1:1:.05, -1:1:.05]

# Apply the function to the values
z = x * y

# Get matplotlib figure and axis
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(3, 3), ncols=1)

# Plot the colormap
pos_neg_clipped = ax.imshow(z, cmap='RdBu', interpolation='none')

# Display the image
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image: Output Image]

Comment: You can use `extent=[x0,x1,y0,y1]` to set the ranges for `imshow`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `imshow`, which should only really be used for plotting images, use [`pcolormesh`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pcolormesh.html), which you can pass the `x` and `y` values for the axes.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.close("all")

x, y = np.mgrid[-1:1:0.05, -1:1:0.05]
z = x*y

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.pcolormesh(x, y, z, cmap="RdBu")
ax.set_aspect(1)
fig.show()
```

[image]